# Could not initialize class (Inteliij Idea) If you have ideas or solutions, please tell me

Tags: java, intellij-idea, initialization

I wanted to create a simple snake game. I tried to find a solution to the problem on the Internet, the answer was only to install the old version of Intellij Idea, I want to learn how to do this in newer versions, not old ones. Gives an error message Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.jps.builders.JpsBuildBundle how to solve the error?

This is first class

```
import javax.swing.*
public class MineWindow extends JFrame {

    public MineWindow(){
        setTitle("Змейка"); //Название программы
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Чтобы программа закрывалась крестиком
        setSize(320,345); //Расширение окна
        setLocation(400,400); //Отступ от экранa
        add(new GameField());
        setVisible(true); // Можно ли видеть окно
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MineWindow mw = new MineWindow();
    }

}
```

This is the second class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;

public class GameField extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private final int size = 320; //размер поля
    private final int dot_size = 16; //Сколько пикселей будет занимать 1 частичка змейки и яблока
    private final int all_dots = 400; //Сколько клеточек в общей сложности
    private Image dot ;// клеточка
    private Image apple ;// яблоко которое будет хавать змея
    private  int appleX;
    private int appleY;
    private int[] x = new int[all_dots];//Массив размерности всего поля
    private int[] y = new int[all_dots];//Тоже самое только для y позиции
    private int dots;
    private Timer timer;
    private boolean left = false;
    private boolean right = true;
    private boolean up = false;
    private boolean down = false;
    private boolean InGame = true;

    public GameField(){ //нужно чтобы посылать доп информацию в окно которое видет игрок
        setBackground(Color.black); //Цвет для игрового поля
        loadImages();
        initGame();
        addKeyListener(new FieldKeyListener());
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    public void initGame(){ //Стартовая позиция змейки
        dots = 3; //начальная длина змейки
        for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++) {
            x[i] = 48 - i * dot_size;//48/16=3 длины змейки 16 это 1 клеточка
            y[i] = 48;
        }
        timer = new Timer(250, (ActionListener) this);
        timer.start();
        createApple();
    }
    public void createApple(){
        appleX = new Random().nextInt(20)*dot_size; //Нужно писать все квадратики чтобы куда-то поставить яблоко
        appleY = new Random().nextInt(20)*dot_size; //чтобы получилось максимально 320
    }

    public void loadImages(){ //Для загрузки картинок
        ImageIcon iia = new ImageIcon("apple.png");
        apple = iia.getImage();
        ImageIcon iid = new ImageIcon("dot.png");
        dot = iid.getImage();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { //для перерисовки игры
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(InGame){
            g.drawImage(apple, appleX, appleY, this);
            for (int i = 0; i < dots; i++) {
                g.drawImage(dot, x[i], y[i], this);
            }
        } else{
            String str = "Game Over";
            Font f = new Font("Arial",14, Font.BOLD);
                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN); //цвет для отрисовки
            g.setFont(f);//задать шрифт
            g.drawString(str, 125, size/2);//Чтобы вивело на экран
        }
    }

    public void move() {
        for (int i = dots; i > 0; i--) { //чтобы хвостик змейки передвигался
            x[i] = x[i - 1];
            y[i] = y[i - 1];
        }
        if (left) {
            x[0] -= dot_size; //чтобы голова змейки передвигалась в нужном направлении а за ней хвостик
        }
        if (right) {
            x[0] += dot_size;
        }
        if(up) {
            y[0] -= dot_size;
        }
        if(down) {
            y[0] += dot_size;
        }
    }
    public void checkApple(){
        if (x[0] == appleX && y[0] == appleY) {
            dots++;
            createApple();
        }
    }
    public void checkCollisions(){
        for (int i = dots; i > 0; i--) {
            if (i > 4 && x[0] == x[i] && y[0] == y[i]){ //Если змейка столкнеться сама с собой то игра закончится
                InGame = false;
            }
        }
        if (x[0] > size){ //если выйдет за поле то игра зкончится
            InGame = false;
        }
        if (x[0] < 0){
            InGame = false;
        }
        if (y[0] > size){
            InGame = false;
        }
        if (y[0] < 0){
            InGame = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(InGame){
            checkApple();
            checkCollisions();
            move();
        }
        repaint();
    }
    class FieldKeyListener extends KeyAdapter{ //это нужно для того чтобы направление нормально менялось
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyPressed(e);
            int key = e.getKeyCode();//какая клавиша была нажата
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && ! right){
                left = true;
                up = false;
                down = false;
            }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && ! left){
                right = true;
                up = false;
                down = false;
            }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && ! down){
                up = true;
                left = false;
                right = false;
            }
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && ! up){
                down = true;
                left = false;
                right = false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What project JDK do you use?